# Auto type () in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Maybe my visual studio is broken. 
I'm hoping when I type something like "Something.ToString()", I can just type "Something." then the intellisense will add the ToString() automatically. Right now, it can add ToString but I have type "()". Is it doable in Visual Studio? 
I heard a Tab will do so but my Tad only add "ToString" not "ToString()". Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try going to "Edit" > "IntelliSense" > "Toggle Completion Mode"

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this has never been implemented. Some may reply that you can modify the "Automatic Brace Completion" setting, but that's only to add a closing bracket when you type an open bracket first.